# Android application has stopped working -eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I have been tried to build my first Android Application. Every time I open the application in the emulator, I just get a message that says test has stopped working. It must be something simple. Hope you can help me.

> 04-06 15:43:47.806: W/dalvikvm(4275): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0xa614d908)
>
> 04-06 15:43:47.826: E/AndroidRuntime(4275): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 04-06 15:43:47.826: E/AndroidRuntime(4275):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.test/com.test.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 04-06 15:43:47.826: E/AndroidRuntime(4275):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>
> 04-06 15:43:47.826: E/AndroidRuntime(4275):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>
> 04-06 15:43:47.826: E/AndroidRuntime(4275):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>
> 04-06 15:43:47.826: E/AndroidRuntime(4275):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>
> 04-06 15:43:47.826: E/AndroidRuntime(4275):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> 04-06 15:43:47.826: E/AndroidRuntime(4275):   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>
> 04-06 15:43:47.826: E/AndroidRuntime(4275):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>
> 04-06 15:43:47.826: E/AndroidRuntime(4275):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 04-06 15:43:47.826: E/AndroidRuntime(4275):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>
> 04-06 15:43:47.826: E/AndroidRuntime(4275):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>
> 04-06 15:43:47.826: E/AndroidRuntime(4275):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>
> 04-06 15:43:47.826: E/AndroidRuntime(4275):   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 04-06 15:43:47.826: E/AndroidRuntime(4275): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 04-06 15:43:47.826: E/AndroidRuntime(4275):   at
>   com.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
>
> 04-06 15:43:47.826: E/AndroidRuntime(4275):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>
> 04-06 15:43:47.826: E/AndroidRuntime(4275):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>
> 04-06 15:43:47.826: E/AndroidRuntime(4275):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>
> 04-06 15:43:47.826: E/AndroidRuntime(4275):   ... 11 more

Above is the log file

```
public class Main extends ActionBarActivity {

    int counter ;
        Button add, sub ;
        TextView display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      counter = 0;
          add = (Button) findViewById (R.id.bAdd);
          sub = (Button) findViewById (R.id.bsub);
          display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
          add.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter++;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);

            }
        });

          sub.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter --;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
            }
        });


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
               .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

        @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

       @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

/**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Above is the Main class

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.test.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bsub"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bsub"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Your total is 0"
        android:textSize="45dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/badd"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Add one"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bsub"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/badd"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Subtract one"
        android:textSize="20dp" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Above is the fragment_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.Hello.firstapp.Main"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

ABove is the activity_main.xml

Comment: You have NullPointerException in line 30 of your MainActivity.java. Check that line.

Comment: @UdoKlimaschewski  add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() This is where I am getting the NullPointerException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `onCreate()` move all ur initialization into `onCreateView()` as those `buttons` and `textview` is in ur `fragment_main.xml` thats why u got `NPE` as those `buttons` and `textview` is not the part of `activity_main.xml`.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
counter = 0;
add = (Button) rootView.findViewById (R.id.bAdd);
sub = (Button) rootView.findViewById (R.id.bsub);
display = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
add.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  counter++;
   display.setText("Your total is " + counter);

    }
   });

  sub.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   counter --;
   display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
   }
  });
 return rootView;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU SO MUCHH!!! I WAS GOING AROUND IN CIRCLESSSSS....YOU ARE A LEGENDDDD

Answer (score 2):

I see your issue. `activity_main.xml` contains a frame layout, in which your `fragment_main.xml` is inflated. The thing is that, both `add` and `sub` are null, as you're looking for them in the wrong layout. Thus, call the FragmentTransaction first and move all your button code to the `onCreateView` of the PlaceHolderFragment and your issue should be fixed. I have provided the fixed code, all you have to do is copy it and remove the button code from `onCreate (...)`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    counter = 0;

    add = (Button) rootView.findViewById (R.id.bAdd);
    sub = (Button) rootView.findViewById (R.id.bsub);
    display = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

    add.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;
            display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
        }
    });

    sub.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             counter --;
             display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU SO MUCHH!!! I WAS GOING AROUND IN CIRCLESSSSS....YOU ARE A LEGENDDDD

Answer (score 0):

Most likely

```
add = (Button) findViewById (R.id.bAdd);
```

returns `null`, because the element is not defined on your activity_main view.

Comment: Well the the thing is I have defined all the buttons in the fragment_main.xml because I cannot add anything to the main_activity.xml. The problem exists in the main class and especially in this method add = (Button) findViewById (R.id.bAdd);

Comment: Then, maybe the fragment is not loaded into the view.

Comment: No that cannot be it because first when I made the buttons in the fragment xml the application worked perfectly and then the problem arrived when I made this button  add = (Button) findViewById (R.id.bAdd);

Comment: Fact is, the button is not found in the view with the given ID. Maybe, you defined it with another id.

Comment: But I have also given this code add = (Button) findViewById (R.id.badd); that brings that particular button and then I wrote add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    counter++;
   }
  });

Comment: Should that not be enough?

Comment: Please show your fragments xml, also your activity_main.xml

Comment: <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.Hello.firstapp.Main"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />

Comment: I cannot seem to add the fragment xml because its too long.

Comment: Add it to your question

Comment: I see two problems: 1) The fragment is not included in the activity_main.xml. Either include it, or simply add the complete RelativeLayout to the activity_main.xml. 2) The button is named badd in the xml, but you try to find bAdd (uppercase A) in your code.

Comment: When I add the whole fragment to the main_activity.xml I am getting this error called "The markup in the document following the root element must be well formed"